# Can Await and Async wait for computation to complete?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a board game similar to Monopoly in JS using HTML. The problem is, multiple events are to occur, strictly one after the other during a players turn. I have one function called takeTurn() in which all events take place. Right now I have no dialogues and only basic player movement, which takes in a random number. So as of its current state, the game can play itself at lightning speeds. Is there any way that I can wait for a function to finish? Async and Await have a strict amount of time they wait, I want something that actually waits for the computation of the function to complete, and a value to be returned? How might I do this.

```
async function takeTurn(who=1) {
    // Move the player on the board.
    calcPos(who);

    // Display the player's money.
    displayBills(who);

    // Change player heading.
    document.getElementById('playerturn').innerText = "Player " + who + "'s Turn";

    // Implement getting out of jail!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // Roll and move.

    // TRY TO GET OUT OF JAIL.
    if (playerdata[who].pos == "jail") {
        console.log(`Player ${who} rolls to attempt to get out of jail.`);
        let roll1 = rollDice();
        let roll2 = rollDice();

        // The player attempts to role doubles and get out of jail.
        if (roll1 == roll2) {
            console.log(`Player ${who} rolled doubles and got out of jail.`);
            move(who, roll1+roll2);
            endTurn(who);
        } else {
            console.log(`Player ${who} failed to roll doubles and is still stuck in jail.`);
            endTurn(who);
        }
    // Move if we aren't in jail.
    } else {
        // Roll the dice.
        console.log(`Player ${who} rolls to move.`);
        let roll1 = rollDice();
        let roll2 = rollDice();
        console.log(`Player ${who} rolls a ${roll1} and a ${roll2}. They move ${roll1+roll2} spaces.`);
        move(who, roll1+roll2);

        // End the turn.
        endTurn(who);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by async/await wait for a strict amount of time? And which function do you want to wait on? It's hard to tell which calls inside `takeTurn` are synchronous and which are async

Comment: `await` can wait indefinitely.

Comment: I want for it to wait for players to roll the dice, this currently only takes a fraction of a second and would make no notable difference, but eventually there will be animation that plays. I also want it to wait for a player to finish move()ing

Comment: That's not a candidate for `await` per-se, it's a candidate for an [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Code :

```
async function takeTurn(who=1) {
// Move the player on the board.
await calcPos(who);

// Display the player's money.
await displayBills(who);

// Change player heading.
document.getElementById('playerturn').innerText = "Player " + who + "'s Turn";

// Implement getting out of jail!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// Roll and move.

// TRY TO GET OUT OF JAIL.
if (playerdata[who].pos == "jail") {
    console.log(`Player ${who} rolls to attempt to get out of jail.`);
    let roll1 = await rollDice();
    let roll2 = await rollDice();

    // The player attempts to role doubles and get out of jail.
    if (roll1 == roll2) {
        console.log(`Player ${who} rolled doubles and got out of jail.`);
        await move(who, roll1+roll2);
        await endTurn(who);
    } else {
        console.log(`Player ${who} failed to roll doubles and is still stuck in jail.`);
        await endTurn(who);
    }
// Move if we aren't in jail.
} else {
    // Roll the dice.
    console.log(`Player ${who} rolls to move.`);
    let roll1 = await rollDice();
    let roll2 = await rollDice();
    console.log(`Player ${who} rolls a ${roll1} and a ${roll2}. They move ${roll1+roll2} spaces.`);
    move(who, roll1+roll2);

    // End the turn.
    await endTurn(who);
}
}
```

This will wait for every function to finish if that `rollDice` not take long time to execute.